# .csv import to R returns warning message "In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :"

Tags: r, text-mining, data-import

I'm attempting to pull description data into R for text mining.

```
file <- read.csv ("file.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

returns the following:

Warning Message
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string

and reduces number of rows by 90%

I have tried adding several things:

```
skipNul=T
sep = ""
quote = ""
```

also:
    read.table('file.csv'....)

all reduce the data by the exact same amount, implying they have no impact on the error

Comment: typo:  sep = ""  -> sep="\n"

Comment: Try `quote = "\""`, but do provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show a preview of the input file you are trying to load? In particular, is the data comma-separated, and are their quotes in the file?

Without knowing more, I would try `quote=NULL` instead of `quote=""` since it seems like the parser is being confounded by the presence of quotation marks.

Also, you may want to `tail` the file to make sure it doesn't end prematurely.